# Time Machine tells me to use it EVERY TIME I insert my external HD

Tags: macos, hard-drive, osx-snow-leopard, time-machine

I use [SuperDuper!](http://www.shirt-pocket.com/SuperDuper) to backup my Mac (running SL 10.6.1)  to my [LaCie Rugged Hard Disk](http://www.lacie.com/uk/products/product.htm?pid=10995).

Because I lock my hard drive away when it's not in use everytime I plug it in it gives me a pop-up box saying:

[image: time machine popup box]

I always click 'Don't Use' but now it always pops up regardless of what I click.

This seems to have only started since I installed Snow Leopard.  When I ran Leopard (10.5) it only appeared once (when I plugged in the HD for the first time).

Is this a new '*feature*' that Apple has included in SL? Or is this not normal, and if so how can I fix it?

**UPDATE:** Sorry Forgot to mention that Time Machine is turned off in system preferences.

Comment: I believe this is governed by some hidden file, what does `ls -la | grep ' \.'` give?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A workaround from [Stop Time Machine from Nagging About Every External Disk](http://www.afp548.com/article.php?story=20080109213724586) at AFP548:

> Every time you plug in a different external disk Time Machine asks if you want to use it for backups. [..] What we need is a way to set a policy that tells Time Machine to not ask about every disk that is plugged in. [..] Here it is:
>
> `defaults write com.apple.TimeMachine DoNotOfferNewDisksForBackup -bool YES`

Answer (score 1):

Small chance (as you did not have this problem in 10.5 Leopard): is SuperDuper! overwriting the whole disk each time? If so, then it might also remove some hidden file that tells Time Machine you want to ignore that disk. (I'm just guessing; maybe that setting is kept in some [extended attribute](http://earthlingsoft.net/ssp/blog/2008/03/x5_time_machine#xattr) rather than in some hidden file.) If it indeed uses some hidden file, and if SuperDuper! deletes that, then maybe you can set that hidden file to be read-only for SuperDuper!? (Funny !?... ;-))

(Hmmm, [this discussion](http://www.shirtpocket.com/forums/showthread.php?t=5429) might cover it: *Did you schedule an erase-then-copy backup, rather than a Smart Update? This is the kind of thing that TM does when a new drive appears...* But you're using Smart Update already.)

Still, Time Machine being switched off, it should not bother you in the first place, so something surely is wrong. Maybe just remove `/Library/Preferences/com.apple.TimeMachine.plist` and disable it again?

Comment: I have seen weird files like `.com.apple.timemachine.supported` pop up on my external drives...

Comment: I think that's something else (people also use that to make Time Machine support network drives that are actually not supported...)

Comment: nope it does a 'Smart Update'

Answer (score 1):

I thought Hasaan Chop's solution would work for me, but I had to do this:

```
defaults write /Library/Preferences/com.apple.TimeMachine DoNotOfferNewDisksForBackup -bool YES
```

Perhaps because I'm on Snow Leopard? Found [on Apple Support](http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?messageID=11676674&#11676674).

Answer (score 0):

If you don't use TM at all you can go into System Preferences > Time Machine and turn it off. This will stop the prompts.

Comment: Sorry Forgot to mention that Time Machine is turned off in system preferences.